# Is there a way to flip the bit under your cursor in (n)vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I do some low level programming which involves a decent about of bit manipulation. It would be very useful if I could somehow flip `1` to `0` and vice versa under my cursor. I couldn't find any built in function or installable plugin, and I don't really know to write a macro for that.

My go to so far is `r` and then typing the bit I want to flip it to, but if there is a way to do this easier (IE, without remembering the previous bit and what I want to flip it to) that would be great.

Currently I just use `r` and then typing the bit, which works but isn't ideal.

Comment: There is no built-in way dedicated to that. `:help ctrl-a` and `:help ctrl-x` are the closest you can get without writing an ad-hoc mapping. If you want a plugin, ask Google.

Answer (score 3):

The following one-liner will flip a 0's and 1's under the cursor:

```
nnoremap <leader>f cl<C-R>=@"=='0'?1:0<CR><Esc>
```

This creates a mapping for `<leader>f` - feel free to pick any key(s) of your choice.

In the mapping, we start with `cl` which will delete the next character and enter insert mode.
In insert mode, we access the expression register through `<C-R>=` and make it evaluate a ternary expression to insert either '0' or '1'. This depends on the value of the default register `"` which conveniently contains the character we just cut thorugh `cl`. With `<CR>` we make the expression register evaluate and the final `<Esc>` will return us to normal mode.

We need `cl` instead of `r` because the latter doesn't allow us to access registers. It also does not populate the default register `"`.

Minor caveat compared to an `r`-based solution is that this will clobber your unnamed register. Most of the time we don't care about it. However, if you find that unacceptable, you could use a sacrificial register both for `cl` and in the ternary's condition.

For reference, see [`:help i_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R), [`:help quote=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D) and [`:help ternary`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#ternary).

Answer (score 2):

Put this code into your `vimrc` file, restart Vim, put cursor where you want to change bit, and hit <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick / key to the left of 1).

This code checks whether bit under cursor is '1', if it is, change it to 0 else change to 1.

```
function! Flip()
    if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == '1'
        normal! r0
    else
        normal! r1
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap ` :call Flip()<CR>
```